# mlogfilter & mongoimport fails in running script in crontab

Tags: linux, bash, mongodb, shell

After logrotate i'm using mtools to filter slow queries and insert those in slowqueries collection by script.

```
# rotate log
mongo admin -eval "db.runCommand({logRotate:1})"
# insert slow queries in database
mlogfilter /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]T* --slow --json |  mongoimport -d pllogs -c slowqueries
# compress roatated logs
for f in /var/log/mongodb/mongod.log.[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]T*;
do
    echo "$f"
        7za a "$f.z" "$f"
        wait
    rm -f "$f"
done
# remove files older than 20 days
find /var/log/mongodb/'*.z' -ctime +20 | xargs rm -rf
```

Script works fine when i run it manually, but when i use crontab for it, compressed logs are there but i can't find slow queries in database.

Comment: You probably need to use the full path to `mongo` and `mlogfilter`

Comment: @arco444 I've added /usr/bin/mlogfilter  & /usr/bin/mongoimport but still its not working.